# Bring the full url into input?

Tags: html, laravel

I have a column in the database to save the URL that I need it.

The column ( type "text" ):

[image]

The input:

[image]

Pls notice the URL in the database and in input:

I used in code this one to bring the value:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Link Of Generall Group</label>
  <input type="text"  name="general_group" value="{{ setting()->general_group }}">
</div>
```

what is setting()? : it's helper function to bring the first query form database:

```
 if (! function_exists('setting') ) {
   function setting(){
    return \App\models\Setting::first();
  }
}
```

The code of controller when I store the setting:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required',
        'descE'=>'required',
        'descA'=>'required',
        'mode'=>'required',
        'general_group'=>'required',
        'lockregisterofadmins'=>'required',
    ]);

    $request_all = $request->except(['_method','_token']);

    setting()->update($request_all);
    session()->flash('success', trans('site.update'));
    return view('backend.setting.index');
}
```

dd for the update request:

[image]

I don't know why the ( https ) does not show in the input?!

Comment: The problem is probably somewhere in your query. Please post all code for this request.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found solution go to your model and add this ->

```
protected $fillable=['col','col'] // col-> column in database :)
```

your model will be in App\models\Setting

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'test';

    protected $fillable=[
        'general_group'
    ];

}
```

if you don't have `$fillable` update maybe don't want execute so try add $fillable where in [] are names of column in your database.

Comment: @ahmed I just edited solution try this i will be waiting for the result